# Double Packages

Tags: 20.04, package-management, lubuntu

I just upgraded from Lubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. Now there are two versions of some programs. I saw that in the installation process it asked me if I wanted to remove redundant packages, but it could take several hours so I declined. Is this my issue? If so is there a way to remove them now? Or do I have to go through the packages that have been replaced with newer versions or a different package altogether?

Results of `snap list` :

```
core core18 core20 gimp gnome-3-28-1804 gnome-3-38-2004 gtk-common-themes gtk2-common-themes nextcloud p7zip-desktop qt513 snapd spotify telegram-desktop ungoogled-chromium
```

I haven't used flatpak.

Comment: Please share output of `snap list` and `flatpak list` commands. Do you see doubled programs in the above command output?

Comment: core core18 core20 gimp gnome-3-28-1804 gnome-3-38-2004 gtk-common-themes gtk2-common-themes nextcloud p7zip-desktop qt513 snapd spotify telegram-desktop ungoogled-chromium. I haven't used flatpak.

Comment: "there are two of some programs" - which exactly?

Comment: Its not the software from snap that I am talking about. Its stuff like having two email clients (sylpheed and trojita) or two pulse audio volume controls in the system tools.

Comment: Sylpheed and Trojita are not duplicates. They are separate applications that coincidentally happen to do the same thing. Usually that happens if folks install more than one Desktop Environment (or DE metapackage) -- each DE has its own application set. Did you happen to do that?

Comment: "*or two pulse audio volume controls*" please try to provide more information (in your Question above, not in comments!). Such a limited statement provides too little for us to work with. You can discover the path to each application, the path to each .desktop file, the package that provides each of those files. Somewhere in the course of your investigation you will discover a difference that explains why there are two.

Comment: @user535733 This is most likely. I got a notification telling me to update from lubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. After the update, new software got installed which does the same function as the old. Currently I am using LXQT. Before it was XFCE.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is the snap version and deb version

Run the command

```
 software-properties-gtk
```

Go to `other software` tab

[image]

Select and remove duplicate entries

Comment: Does source code count as duplicate? Because only canonical partners and canonical partners (source code) is ticked.